# Insert into tempTable and Select From tempTable queries inside while loop

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-insert, temp-tables

I have a PHP loop which contains two sql queries. One is an INSERT INTO a temp_Table. The other, a SELECT * FROM temp_Table. The SELECT statement is executed multiple times and my results are incorrect as there are repetitions. Is there a way of just executing the SELECT statement once, after all the INSERT INTO statements have finished executing?

```
while(odbc_fetch_row($gotdaysreports)){

 $insertQuery = "insert into temp_Table (
   REPORTNR,
   ACCOUNTNO,
   ACCOUNTNAME,
   USERNAME,
   TOTALVALUE,
   TOTALTAX,
   DISCOUNT,
   DISCTAX,
   DISCOUNT )select  * from SUPPLIER_PURCHASES( $company_id,$branchindex,$regionindex,$dayendid ,$accountnumber)";

$selectQuery = "select * from temp_Table";  
}

$gotinsertQuery = odbc_exec($connect, $insertQuery);

$gotselectQuery = odbc_exec($connect, $selectQuery);
```

The select statement should run once after the INSERTS have finished. Currently, it executes for each insert.

Comment: So just take it out of the loop, no?

Comment: ...also, the above code would only make one insert (the last one in the loop) since you're overwriting the `$insertQuery`-variable on every iteration. It would also only make one single select. You're currently not actually doing anything but defining the same variables over and over inside the loop.

Comment: @PatrickQ The insert depends on the while loop. Two parameters on the stored procedure are assgned values within the loop

Comment: Right, but take the select out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it out of the while loop, concat the insert statements and it will work like a charm.

```
 while(odbc_fetch_row($gotdaysreports)){

 $insertQuery.= "insert into temp_Table (
   REPORTNR,
   ACCOUNTNO,
   ACCOUNTNAME,
   USERNAME,
   TOTALVALUE,
   TOTALTAX,
   DISCOUNT,
   DISCTAX,
   DISCOUNT )select  * from SUPPLIER_PURCHASES( $company_id,$branchindex,$regionindex,$dayendid ,$accountnumber);";

}
 $selectQuery = "select * from temp_Table"; 

$gotinsertQuery = odbc_exec($connect, $insertQuery);

$gotselectQuery = odbc_exec($connect, $selectQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you all - @Patrick Q . I followed your advice and it worked.